# Yarn start doesn't provide me with network address to view website on mobile

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

So I'm fairly new to web development and am working on a project. Usually when I run 'yarn start' I get two addresses I can view my app on:

1. the local host
2. the network address.

I made some changes to my project recently and now I don't get any addresses provided (although the app opens in chrome on the localhost address) instead I just get a list of eslint warnings. I've tried navigating on mobile to my network address with the app extension "192......1:3001" and it doesn't work.

What do I need to change to be able to view my app on my mobile device?

Comment: You need to console.log that information yourself. If you are using express template then do that in www under bin

Comment: log that information? It was in the terminal before directly after running the "yarn start" cmd

Comment: can you share how it looks with your www file?